# When working with accuweather API with JavaScript, console throws an error

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api, console.log, weather-api

This is the error message I'm getting in browser's console.

```
index.html:1 Access to fetch at <'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=8j7t0np4nHcDaTHN6tXFt4eJc8AWJ2ZT&q=manchester'> from origin <'http://127.0.0.1:5500'> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have exceeded your API request limit for your plan.
When you paste this URL '*[http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=8j7t0np4nHcDaTHN6tXFt4eJc8AWJ2ZT&q=manchester*'](http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=8j7t0np4nHcDaTHN6tXFt4eJc8AWJ2ZT&q=manchester*%27) in a browser, you can see the following response:

{"Code":"ServiceUnavailable","Message":"The allowed number of requests has been exceeded.","Reference":"/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=8j7t0np4nHcDaTHN6tXFt4eJc8AWJ2ZT&q=manchester"}